# Redirect to Keycloak login page on unauthenticated access with spring boot 3

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

I am having a really hard time to get Keycloak work fine together with Spring Boot 3 / Spring Security 6. I think most of the examples in the web are outdated and many libs are no more compatible to work with Spring Boot 3.

In principle everything works fine and I can only access my oauth2 secured endpoints when sending a bearer token along with the request that I got manually from Keycloak.

But the behavior of an unauthenticated request that I expect (and that I read in all the examples) is that I get redirected to the login page of keycloak to authenticate myself. Instead I only get a 401 answer.

I have got a relatively simple security configuration:

```
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

  private final KeycloakJwtTokenConverter keycloakJwtTokenConverter;

  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeHttpRequests(
            requestMatcherRegistry -> requestMatcherRegistry
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated());

    http
        .oauth2ResourceServer(resourceServerConfigurer -> resourceServerConfigurer
            .jwt(jwtConfigurer -> jwtConfigurer
                .jwtAuthenticationConverter(keycloakJwtTokenConverter)));

    http
        .sessionManagement(sessionManagementConfigurer -> sessionManagementConfigurer
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));

    return http.build();
  }
}
```

and this application.yaml

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: http://localhost:443/realms/my-realm-name
          jwk-set-uri: ${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri}/protocol/openid-connect/certs
```

Do I have to make an additional configuration to achieve my wanted behavior?

I read the Keycloak and Spring Security 6 documentation. Because of the many outdated examples in the web I had no success with finding out how to achieve my wanted behavior by myself.

What I want is a redirect to the Keycloak Login page when I make an unauthentiacted request to my Spring Boot Endpoint.

Comment: If you have a web-app as client, you should redirect to Keycloak whenever spring-boot[backend] returns 401. That's the right way to do it. You should understand the Roles in [Oauth2](https://auth0.com/docs/authenticate/protocols/oauth)

Comment: When we talk about OAuth, there are generally 3 things which come into picture. First, the resource APi which we want to protect, second, the Authorization server/oauth2 provider, and third is the application which is accessing the API which could be a resource itself or OAuth client where the user is authenticating herself. So, when you talk about login page, you basically want OAuth client part.

Comment: *But the behavior of an unauthenticated request that I expect (and that I read in all the examples) is that I get redirected to the login page of keycloak to authenticate myself.* That's wrong, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/index.html

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Yes I understand the roles of Oauth2. I currently have only a backend with a simple rest endpoint and no frontend (not yet). I access my endpoint with either the browser or curl. With curl I would expect a 301 state and with the browser a redirect to the keycloak login page like described e.g. here: https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-3-keycloak
So no client part is implemented right now, bot the cal to the backend should redirect to the keycloak login page.

Comment: @Mortl  No, as I already wrote in my comment, an OAuth2 resource server is not redirecting you to the OAuth2 authorisation server. This is part of the OAuth2 client. If you don't implemented one, there is no redirection.